# UISlider bounds and frame width returning incorrect values

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uislider

I've subclassed UISlider in order to add some ticks to it.

To get the width of the slider, I'm using:

self.bounds.size.width

Also, self.frame.size.width always returns the same thing.

Trouble is, if I base my tick spread off of the value that this gives me, The outer ticks consistently end up at the edge of the screen. See the screenshots.

[image: Wide View]

Any help or insight is extremely welcome!

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: If you take a view than try self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: UISlider is not a view, it is a Control, so self.view is undefined.  Code is here: https://github.com/justhum/HUMSlider/pull/8/files

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `trackRectForBounds` instead. This will give you the actual frame of the track. If you have constraints and/or do other setup of the slider it is better to get the rect in `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    (super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect r = [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds];
    CGFloat startPosition = r.origin.x;
    CGFloat width = r.size.width;
}
```

*Collaborative update to achieve a working solution:*
 If you've setup constraints, check to see if they are still the right sizes here, and if not, you'll have to update some of their constants, then call [self layoutIfNeeded] to do it again. Be careful though, doing this every time would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Doesn't work, my code is this, and using the value still makes it inaccurate: 
[self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds].size.width

Comment: You also need to start at [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds].origin.x

Comment: Another thing that might be a problem is that you need to wait for sizes and positions to finalize. This is especially important if you are using constraints. Best place to do these things are in `layoutSubviews`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice. I'll try this. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This is correct, but I must add that I had to check to see if my constraints sill matched what I setup before from the previous width. If they didn't, then I would have to update the constraint's constant values again within the layoutSubviews method, and then call [self layoutIfNeeded]